# extract left of the question mark

Tags: c#

Is there a quick way to grab everything left of the question mark?

```
http://blah/blah/?blah

to 

http://blah/blah/
```

Comment: Is it going to be the only '?' in this line?

Comment: Please specify what language you're working in... for example, javascript, C#, Regex, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://blah/blah/?blah");
 string leftPart = uri.OriginalString.Replace(uri.Query,string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want to use `string.Split`:

```
string url = @"http://blah/blah/?blah";
var parts = url.Split('?');

string bitToLeftOfQuestionMark = parts[0];
```

Comment: Everything to the _left_ of the question mark would be parts[0]

Comment: He was looking for the parts before the question mark, which would be parts[0].  But really, he didn't say what language he was working in, so who knows?

Comment: @_rusty - I spotted that - refresh the page.

Comment: @ChrisW - yep - slip of the brain. Now corrected - also question is tagged C# so that's what I assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string httpString = "http://blah/blah/?blah"

int questionMarkLocation = httpString.indexOf('?');

string newString = httpString.Substring(questionMarkLocattion+1);
```

Comment: Add `string remainingString = httpString.Substring(questionMarkLocattion+1)` for completeness and you got all you need.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you essentially want to get the scheme, authority and path of the URI.

You can use the [Uri.GetComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx) Method for this:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://blah/blah/?blah");
var result = uri.GetComponents(
                     UriComponents.SchemeAndServer | UriComponents.Path,
                     UriFormat.UriEscaped);

//  result == "http://blah/blah/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a **different** answer:

```
var url = "http://blah/blah/?blah";
var leftPart = Regex.Match(url, @"[^?]+").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Leverage [`GetLeftPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart?view=net-7.0) with `UriPartial.Path` which:

Includes any delimiters in the original URI up to the query or fragment delimiter.

`uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)`